# jquery get the last tr with a th

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

using jquery how do alter the css of the last tr with a th

```
$("#mytable tr").has('th').last().parents('tr').css({'color':'blue'});
```

HTML

```
<table border="1" id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th>row 1, cell 1</th>
        <th>row 1, cell 2</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <th>row 1, cell 1 - change this</th>
        <th>row 1, cell 2 - change this</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And what happens if you do this? And what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative to [xdazz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472153/82548), I'd offer:

```
$('tr:has(th):last').css('color','blue');
```

References:

- [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).

Comment: +1 I never really understood if quotes had any special meaning within `:has()` in jQuery (I know they're invalid within `:not()`).

Comment: I'm never quite sure myself; I tend to include them simply because it *feels* right.

Comment: It feels wrong to me, as you're passing a selector rather than a string :/ Having quotes on `:has()` but not on `:not()` seems inconsistent to me as well...

Comment: ...and edited (having looked at the [API](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), in which it's *implied* that the quotes are unnecessary; but not explicitly stated either way.

Comment: Apparently, quotes *are* allowed, both in `:not()` and `:has()`. I've posted a question asking why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475595/why-do-jquerys-not-and-has-selectors-allow-quoted-arguments

Answer (score 5):

Find the last `th`, and its parent should be the last `tr` who has `th`.

```
$("#mytable th:last").parent().css('color', 'blue');
```